# Auto tab when enter a newline in MathType

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, mathtype

How I can set up MathType to make an automate tab in Mathtype everywhen an enter key is pressed.
For example:

```
A = a(b+d)
= ab+ad
```

After setting up

```
A = a(b+d)
  = ab+ad
```

The equal symbol "=" is auto lined up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to do this in MathType. Going strictly by the way you asked your question, method 1 or method 3 may be the best.

1. Use MathType's "Align" settings. There is a setting in the Format menu for this, but none of the horizontal alignment options are available until there is more than one line: [image: Setting horizontal alignment options in MathType]
   After you press Enter, the Align options will become available and you can choose
   **Align at = < > ...**. There is not a way to make this happen automatically when you press Enter.
2. Use a "relational tab". Choose this one from the "tab well": [image: MathType's tab well pane]. Place it at the point along the ruler where you want all the = symbols to align (including the first line). Press Ctrl+Tab to move to the tab's position (it's the same on Windows and Mac). If you want them to align exactly, you must press Ctrl+Tab even on the first line too.
3. Use a matrix. Don't use one of the pre-configured sizes; choose "variable-size matrix": [image: Add a variable-size matrix to MathType for equation alignment.]
   Set the options to have always 1 column and always "Column alignment: At =". (It will align at any relational symbol, not just the = symbol.) Set the number of rows to be the same as the number of equations you have.
   [image: MathType matrix settings]
   When you get to the end of one line, don't press Enter; press Tab to go to the next row in the matrix. When you're finished, press Tab again to exit the matrix, close MathType to insert the set into Word, or copy & paste to other applications.